# How to create a Tamil Calendar

Tags: calendar, tamil

I want to create a calendar in Tamil. I have searched extensively, but all the results show how to convert the text in the calendar from other languages to Tamil. But I want to create the whole Tamil calendar for the Tamil year. I would highly appreciate any help in creating a calendar in Tamil from scratch.

Another task where I need some help is to convert English date into equivalent Tamil date.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tamilcalendar/files/tamilcalendar/Tamil%20calendar%201.0/

Comment: http://store.ovi.com/content/132613

Comment: Above 2 links has samples ...

Comment: You can refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_calendar